# Running Node JS server on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I want to make a very simple web server like this for example.

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.write("Hello!");
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

I put this code in WebStorm and ran it. Then I put in the same directory index.html file.

```
<body>
    <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="requester.js"></script>
</body>
```

I also put requester.js file in the same folder.

```
$('#btn').on("click", function () {
    $.get('/', function () {
        console.log('Successful.');
    });
});
```

Then I execute command live-server in this folder where all files are. I don't know how to make the server to work on localhost. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You havent shown any effort to actually send the file to the user. Have a look at http://expressjs.com, especially their .static method...

Comment: I need to do this only with http module. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at .sendFile, fs.readFile, Streams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to send your `index.html` file instead of the string "Hello":

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    //NOTE: This assumes your index.html file is in the 
    // .    same location as your root application.
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');
    const stat = fs.statSync(filePath);

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        'Content-Length': stat.size
    });

    var stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    stream.pipe(res);
}).listen(8080);
```

Depending on the complexity of your server in the future, you may want to investigate [express](https://expressjs.com/) as an alternative to the built-in http module.